# Como carregar as configuracoes do persistence.xml no ComboPooledDataSource?

Tags: java, hibernate

Configurei o C3P0 via persistence.xml, entretanto, quando tento recuperar os valores de configuracao via ComboPooledDataSource os valores recebidos estao discrepantes do que foi configurado no arquivo de configuracao.

```
 <properties>    
            <!-- Configurações específicas do Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <!-- Propriedades JDBC -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/financas" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123" />

            <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize" value="10"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
        </properties>
```

E no java:

```
EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();

ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
System.out.println("Numero de conexoes: " + ds.getMaxPoolSize());
```

Creio eu que o valor retornado pelo getMaxPoolSize() deveria ser 20, mas esta retornando 15.

E agora? como carregar as configuracoes do persistence.xml no ComboPooledDataSource?

----------------- ATUALIZADO ---------

Adicionei as propriedades :

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
```

Mas o java continua retornando maxPoolSize = 15 e agora?

Comment: tenta adicionar `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="20" />`

Comment: Vc pode definir também diretamente pelo pool,
`ds.setMinPoolSize(10);
ds.setMaxPoolSize(20);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Propriedades corretas:

Mude isso:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize" value="10"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
```

Para:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
```

#### Por que o trecho abaixo não funciona?

```
ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
System.out.println("Numero de conexoes: " + ds.getMaxPoolSize());
```

Porque o que você está fazendo ali é criar um novo `ComboPooledDataSource` e recuperando o valor padrão dele, 15. Para você recuperar o definido na configuração do Hibernate você precisa obter o `DataSource` gerenciado pelo Hibernate.

#### Como obter o max_size do DataSource utilizado pelo Hibernate?

```
WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource wrapper = 
        (WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource) entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class)
                                                .getServiceRegistry()
                                                .getService(ConnectionProvider.class)
                                                .unwrap(PoolBackedDataSource.class)
                                                .getConnectionPoolDataSource();

System.out.println(wrapper.getMaxPoolSize());
System.out.println(wrapper.getMinPoolSize());
```

Não sei porque você quer recuperar esses valores. Isso é, de certa forma, inseguro, já que para fazer isso você precisa referenciar classes e métodos internos do Hibernate e não há garantias de que eles estarão presentes em versões futuras.

Se você quer apenas saber eles para garantir que os valores utilizados no seu `persistence.xml` correspondem aos utilizados pelo `c3p0`, saiba que durante a inicialização do Hibernate é feito o *logging* dessas informações no *console*. Aparece algo parecido com isso:

```
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@3f738772 [//as informações aparecem aqui dentro]
```

Answer (score 1):

faltou incluir dentro do persistente o limite do pool

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize" value="10"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
```